# Flask form not getting validated

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

My flask form is not getting validated.

```
 @admin_blueprints.route('/ManageMovies',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
 def ManageMovie():

 form = SetShowForm(request.form)

 if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():

      print(form.movie.data)

      return redirect(url_for('admin.AdminHome'))



 engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://DESKTOP-6UNRAN0/movie_f?driver=SQL Server? 
 Trusted_Connection=yes')

 form.movie.choices = [(movie.m_id, movie.m_name)for movie in (engine.execute('select * from 
 MovieMaster'))]

 form.show_time.choices = [(time.s_id, time.s_time) for time in (engine.execute('select * from 
 ShowTime'))]



 return render_template('manage_movies.html',form=form)
```

my template code is

```
 {% extends "master.html" %}


 {% block content %}

  <form method="POST">

   {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
   {{form.movie.label}}{{form.movie(class="form-control")}}
   <br>
   {{ form.show_time.label }} {{form.show_time(class="form-control")}}
   <br>
   {{form.price.label}} {{ form.price(class="form-control") }}

   <br>
   {{form.submit(class="btn btn-success")}}
   </form>



   {% endblock %}
```

my flask form

```
 class SetShowForm(FlaskForm):
       movie = SelectField('Movie Name', choices=[])
       show_time = SelectField('Set Show Time',choices=[])
       price = IntegerField('Price')

       submit = SubmitField("Set")
```

Once I click on my submit button, the same page gets rendered again instead of entering my (if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():) statement and printing the data. I have no idea what is going wrong. I am filling all the fields. Are there any rule for form validation.

Comment: You're dynamically adding the choices to your form. You need to move this code before you try to test for validation. I.e. currently when you check for validation your form doesn't know anything about the valid choices.

Comment: I removed the (form.validate()) and just kept (request.method == POST). The code started working properly. How and is it a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to use:

```
if form.validate_on_submit():
```

And you don't need to check for "POST" because `validate_on_submit` does that too.

Answer (score 0):

Try it

```
 @admin_blueprints.route('/ManageMovies',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def ManageMovie():

form = SetShowForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():

  print(form.movie.data)

  return redirect(url_for('admin.AdminHome'))

return render_template('manage_movies.html',form=form)
```

And set choices values in setShowForm() directly

Comment: I removed the (form.validate()) and just kept (request.method == POST). The code started working properly. How and is it a good practice.

Comment: good practice is to use  `validate_on_submit()`  which automatically takes requests sent by POST. i have update my answer check it.